# Change primary key from string to Int for users in ASP.NET Identity 2.0 - Worth the trouble?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm going to migrate a database from Parse.com to SQL-server since Parse is shutting down. The new system will use Identity 2.0 that uses a string as primary key by default. To change primary key from string to int seems pretty straight forward looking at the documentation and other threads here on SO.

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

My question is, and this I could not find a good answer for, is it worth the trouble? The application has around 4,5k users today, the system should be able to handle a lot more, and we are doing a lot of query's to the database for users and how they are connected to each other.

Answer (score 0):

In case of data migration I would recommend to migrate all data with old IDs. Not because of system performance but just playing safe. Because other table might use your users current IDs and changing them might lead to big mess.
Also you do not need to change GUID to Int. You can keep both :) In similar situation I just added one more int unique index field to Identity AspNetUsers table.